# Position a foreignObject to the top-right of an svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, foreignobject

I'm adding a `foreignObject` to a chart built upon `svg`. I want to put it on the top-right of the `svg`, irrespective of how big/small that `svg` is. So I don't want a hardcoded solution, I need a dynamic solution.

Setting `width={'100%'} height={'100%'}` inside the `foreignObject` isn't workable, because it makes the rest of the chart unclickable.

I've got a non-dynamic solution by setting `x` and `y` manually inside `foreignObject`, but I need a dynamic solution.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

```
<g>
    <foreignObject //x={0} y={0} 
    width={'1'} height={'1'} style={{overflow: 'visible'}} x={50} y={50}>
     <Menu>
        <MenuButton as={Button} rightIcon={<ChevronDownIcon />}         
        transition="all 0.001s"
        borderRadius="md"
        borderWidth="0px"
        _hover={{ bg: "gray.400" }}
        _expanded={{ bg: "blue.400" }}
        _focus={{ boxShadow: "none" }}
        style={{ marginTop: "1px", position: "absolute", right: 0 }}>
          Actions
        </MenuButton>
        <Portal>
        <MenuList zIndex={10}>
          <MenuItem>Download</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Create a Copy</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Mark as Draft</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Delete</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Attend a Workshop</MenuItem>
        </MenuList>
        </Portal>
      </Menu>
    </foreignObject>
</g>
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-water-v11gx?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx

Comment: In your sample code, you're already passing `width` into `ChartCanvas`. Why not pass it into `TestMenu` as well (`<TestMenu width={width}/>`), to generalize your current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent component `BasicLineSeries` already knows the `width`, so you can pass that into the component generating the `foreignObject` as follows:

```js
       <ChartCanvas
          height={height}
          ratio={ratio}
          width={width}
          ...
        >
          <Chart id={1} yExtents={this.yExtents}>
            <LineSeries yAccessor={this.yAccessor} strokeWidth={3} />
            <XAxis />
            <YAxis />
          </Chart>
          <TestMenu width={width} />
        </ChartCanvas>
```

```js
function TestMenu({width}) {
  return (
    <g className="react-financial-charts-enable-interaction">
      <foreignObject
        width={"1"}
        height={"1"}
        style={{ overflow: "visible" }}
        x={width}
        y={50}
      >
```

Comment: and here is a working codesandbox which implements your idea: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-meadow-604hv?file=/src/BasicLineSeries.tsx